# Long digit random number create algorithm

Tags: php, algorithm, random

I want to create long digit random number in php but there is one question on my mind. What is the best way for performance.

For example first option that i thought.

```
rand(10000,99999)
```

but i don't know how would performance be with this. how would it be if even longer?

so i think of this

```
$randomNumber=rand(10,99).rand(10,99).rand(10,99)...
```

is it more efective than first one?

Thank you.

Comment: `$randomNumber=rand(10000,99999)` - overhead of a single function call; `$randomNumber=rand(10,99).rand(10,99).rand(10,99)` - overhead of three function calls, plus the overhead of the concatenation

Comment: Your first example is 5 times faster +/- than the second one.

Comment: If you're really worrying about that level of performance optimisation in your code, then I assume that you're already addressed the big performance overheads such as loops inside loops, database tuning, etc that really are a big overhead.... but somehow I doubt it

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function RandomNumber()
{
    $size = '15';
    $randomnumber = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $size ; $i++) {
        $randomnumber .= rand(0,9);
    }
    return $randomnumber;
}

$random = RandomNumber();
echo $random;
```

Comment: This will only create one random digit number, means `0-9`

Comment: Just had a quick test and corrected the answer. Thankx

Answer (score 0):

You can use MD5() or if you are using mysql then UUID().  otherwise rand(10000,99999) is OK .

Answer (score 0):

rand(10000,99999)
use of above function is pragmatically and logically very good advise than other options